# Heart Rate from from Polar, Garmin Heart Strap in iOS

Tags: ios, healthkit, garmin

Is it possible to read the Heart Rate directly from a Polar or Garmin Heart Rate Strap in iOS?
Would anybody be willing to share a Swift example for doing this?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor

Comment: You won't be able to read the Garmin strap, as they use Ant+ protocol and Apple devices do not have Ant+ radios. (Some android phones do have this). You can read from the Polar H7 strap as it uses Bluetooth LE.

Comment: There is an adapter available to plug into iPhone to receive ANT+ protocol (https://thesufferfest.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/212904403-Connecting-ANT-Devices)